# How to hide <li> with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ejs

I have two `<ul></ul>` elements. One that has links and the other with content I want to display depending on which link is clicked on.
Here's the code for the `<ul>'s`:

```
<div class="container">
  <ul id="filter">
    <li class="current"><a href="#">Attendess (Middle School/High School Students)</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Attendees (College Students)</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Mentor/Vounteer</a></li>
</ul>

<ul id="forms">
    <li class="Attendess (Middle School/High School Students)"> <% include ./forms/Students %> </li>
    <li class="Attendees (College Students)"> <% include ./forms/college %> </li>
    <li class="Mentor/Vounteer"> <% include ./forms/attendees %> </li>
</ul>
```

Now with jQuery, I implemented the functionality to select different filters but when I do my forms don't hide.

Here's the code for that:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#filter a").click(function(){
        $("#filter .current").removeClass("current");
        $(this).parent().addClass("current");
        var filterVal = $(this).text();
        $("#forms li").fadeIn();
        $("#forms li").not("." + filterVal).fadeOut();
      });
    });
```

Let me know what you guys think?

Comment: Node.js is not jquery and jquery is not node.js. Pleae remove node.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have changed some part of your code. A class must not be spaced. A spaced class means: multiple classes.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#filter a").click(function() {
    $("#filter .current").removeClass("current");
    $(this).parent().addClass("current");
    var filterVal = $(this).data('index');
    $("#forms li").fadeIn();
    $("#forms li:not(." + filterVal + ")").hide();
  });
});
```

```css
.college,
.attendees {
  display: none;
}
a:hover{
  cursor:pointer;
  text-decoration:underline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <ul id="filter">
    <li class="current"><a data-index="students">Attendess (Middle School/High School Students)</a></li>
    <li><a data-index="college">Attendees (College Students)</a></li>
    <li><a data-index="attendees">Mentor/Vounteer</a></li>
  </ul>

  <ul id="forms">
    <li class="students">
      <% include ./forms/Students %>
    </li>
    <li class="college">
      <% include ./forms/college %>
    </li>
    <li class="attendees">
      <% include ./forms/attendees %>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: that worked. Thank you so much. I have one more question when you first load the page all three forms li are loaded. How do I make it so only student li is loaded? Thanks.

Comment: add style with `.college,.attendees{display:none;}` . Updated the code check it.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks, bro. Is there a way for me to remove the .fadeIn() cuz when I click on different links everything fades in for a sec then it goes back to normal. I promise this is the last question?

Comment: Nobody here has any problem with listening to questions. We are here to help. So you don't want fadeIn()?. Check the edited code and feel free to ask any questions. I didn't remove fadeIn(). But made it normal.

Comment: Again, worked like a charm. Thanks. I gotta work on my UI skills lol. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164486/discussion-between-spirit-and-rocky-singh).